# How to copy and crop feature map in Unet?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

[image]

I am confused about the principle of copy and crop in U-net, like the grey line shown above.
For example, the first grey line, how to convert a (64, 568, 568)(C,W,H) to a (128, 392, 392), did the author use conv or crop feature map directly in each channel? I didn't find answer in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf).

If croping meaning only take the central part of feature map in each channel, what about the info in border?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I'm currently working myself on a problem that involves U-Nets and my best guess is that you must use a crop layer on the contraction path, like literally a cropping2D and crop only the size that you need for the corresponding layer on the ascending path.